# Is there a way to continuously check text field input without the user ever hitting the "Return" key?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

For example the user types dog in the text field, and it immediately does an action when they type that.

Comment: Once Google before asking this kind of question! [Refer Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a notification as

```
[yourTextField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

or simply add delegate of UITextField as below

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string {    
  //your code here...
}
```

Comment: The user still has to press the space bar for the input to be registered. I tried that earlier :(.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: The computer checks user input as it is being typed and immediately performs an action once a designated word has been typed. This kinda works  "- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)" but a space is required after the designated word has been typed and then it performs the action.

Answer (score 1):

You can get event on this textfield delegate method

```
 public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    return true;
}
```